# c++ problem | i want to NOT open the console while an program running

Tags: c++, windows, console

Ya know the console opens everytime when u execute an c++ script in any way i am making currently an GDI effect and this Console shows in the background up Here is the script but i dont think the script affects everything :/[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAC7s.png)

Comment: You should build a Windows subsystem program, not a console subsystem program.

Comment: C++ doesn't do scripts. You write source code and you compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=msvc-170) with [WinMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point).

Alternatively, you could hide the console.

```cpp
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: yes but where should i put the script in that u send me in my script?

Comment: @StefanKostov where ever you want it to hide? Put in inside your main, the very first line to execute.

Comment: @StefanKostov C++ is not a scripting language. There is no such thing as "C++ script".

Comment: In case of GCC; the equivalent of `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is either `-mwindows` or `--subsystem,windows` (I believe they also add GDI libraries to link line).